# Jquery dragstart and dragend events in Jquery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Is there somehow a way to access these two events? Do the even exsist?
I have to set transfer data on `dragStart` and `dragEnd` to an `event` object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check:

Drag start: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start

Drag stop: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

You are able to access current event in both function calls.