# how i can put this code running on mobile devicds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i Want to run this code on my mobile phone but if i try to move the picture it don't move and there is no reaction how can i keep this code running on mobile

thanks der122345

```js
copy = 1;
$('.dragArea img').on('dragstart',function(e) {
 console.log('dragge it!',e);
 e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text",e.target.id);
}).on('dragend',function(e) {
 console.log('dragged',e);
});

$('.drop-field').on('dragover',function(e) {
 //console.log('dragover',e);
 e.preventDefault();
}).on('drop',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 //window.status = 'successfully dragged';
 console.log('drop',e,window.status);
 data = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 $(this).append(copy ? $('#' + data).clone() : $('#' + data));
});
```

```css
.drop-field {
 border: 4px #287CA1 dashed;
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragArea">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-g-640-480-4.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="logo" id="logo" />
</div>
<div class="dropArea">
 <span class="drop-field"></span>
 <span class="drop-field"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery dragstart and dragend events in Jquery UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342172/jquery-dragstart-and-dragend-events-in-jquery-ui)

Comment: i want to use the code on an mobile device on computer its working

Comment: Look at this, seems like an answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940421/how-to-get-jqueryui-drag-drop-working-with-touch-devices

Answer (score 1):

Native drag and drop is not supported on mobile. You will need to resort to either:

1. The [Touch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events), using `touchmove` and `touchend`:

   ```
   el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
   el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
   el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
   el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
   ```
2. The [Drag and Drop shim](https://github.com/timruffles/ios-html5-drag-drop-shim) which only supports iOS.
3. Or [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) with [Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/).

It really all depends on what browser support you're looking for and how much of your code are you willing to rewrite.